# How to get the thread model inside GCC?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc, posix

It is easy to do using the command line `gcc -v' but is there a preprocessor variable which indicates the thread model (posix, single, ...)?

Comment: It's not the full thread model, but in gcc, `_REENTRANT` can be used to distinguish between single and multi threading

Comment: `__WINPTHREADS_VERSION` can be used to determine if using posix.. else you are using win32.